# Magmi few rows with same SKU error

Tags: translation, magmi

I´m using magmi to import products with different names (depending on the language selected in store)
Watching the CSV file exported by magento, I had founded that in the first row all product data is stored and in the following one, there is only the fields you wish to add to the "store view" to the desired language (French, in this case ---> fr).

If I empty the database and imported from the CSV magento own, I successfully created the products and the different names and descriptions for each store view.

The problem is that Magmi tells me I need the SKU on the 3rd line, because logically not find the SKU. Using the same SKU in the second and third line, the last line always prevails introduced, crushing the previous.
Any idea how I could intruducir with Magmi, the names and descriptions in other languages without smash the previus data? .... I begin to be a bit desperate!

CSV example rows:

sku;_store;_attribute_set;_type;_category......... name .......short_description ..etc
09110-296555;fr;Default;simple;books;products...name_english ..description_english
;fr;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;name_french......... description_french

Comment: Post your actual CSV data in text format.  You cannot expect us to debug it without the actual real data you're using.

Comment: you are using the wrong csv format (i guess you are using magento import/export format, which is clearly stated as not compatible with magmi csv datasource in the magmi UI)

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your response. What I posted is what my CSV file contains.I will try to explain clearly the rows of my csv
1- row with diferents data categories 
2- row with product data
3- row with just the data i want to introduce for french store view
,fr,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,fr_name,,,,,,,fr_short_description

If i jut introduce de 2 row, will be no problem, the trouble i found is when I try to introduce de 3 row to insert de french name and description for de product whith sku number 296555
Magmi just askme for the nonexistent sku number in this row, and refuse to insert data.

Comment: Thank´s for your response @dweeves . I think it too. but, can you help me to find a Magmi full compatible CSV for the duty I have to do?. Or may be, indicate me how to fix this problem with the current CSV?. I really need to insert new names and descriptions to the products!

Comment: http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2012/11/magento-raw-product-import-csv-creation/ has a good csv sample.

Comment: Thanks man! Looks usefull for me!!!